# ehcache regions better to have a lot of them or as few as possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

When running my application with EHcache, I am getting

```
WARN  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
```

I understand, that I didn't specified any region and that he is creating some defaults for that.

I wanted to fix this, but I cannot seem to find out some documentation that explains what exactly are the regions, and whether it is better to put many entities into one region (e.g. codebook entities) or if it is better to have one region per entity.

Could somebody explain and maybe link some dokumentation or tutorial?

I believe this might be useful to more people, since when I google it i find nothing really relevant for me as a first-time user of ehcache (or any cache).

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know ehcache, but I just googled "configure ehcache regions" and got a lot of hits.

Comment: @NomadMaker well then feel free to link me the answer, because I was going through the pages and didn't find the answer to my questions above. Thank you